# Нужна ли запятая в сложном предложении перед союзом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед и?

> Он все капризничал и я уже с ног сбилась, чем бы его развлечь, чтобы
> он не плакал.

Comment: Hanu, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

*(1) **Он все капризничал, и (2) я уже с ног сбилась**, (3) чем бы его развлечь, (4) чтобы он не плакал.*

Запятая перед союзом И ставится. Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью.

Союз И стоит между простым предложением (1) и сложноподчиненным предложением, состоящим из трех предложений (2), (3) и (4) с последовательным подчинением.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133692/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------).